# iOS 9 Nodes disappearing

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, sprite-kit, ios9

I've had the app released on the app store for about 2 months. Everything in the app worked fine for iOS 8, but after upgrading to iOS 9, some of the apps nodes disappear, which isn't consistent as they sometimes reappear when you go back onto the scene. I've read about the teething problems with z positions. I'm not too sure what to do, I can update my app and have it sent off today, trying to fix the problem.. but this is going to take at least 5 days to have it updates for the app store. If this is a problem with xCode and Apple sort it out, will it take effect on my current app version or will I need to re-submit anyway?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will solve your problem, but it worked for me. I've read a lot about how apparently there's an issue/new way the z.position is determined. You have 2 options. 
1) set the z.position of each node manually OR
2)find skView.ignoreSiblingsOrder = YES and set it to NO (with this method you will have to be mindful of the order you add children). 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah I've been reading a lot about these problems, looks like loads of people had trouble. I've set the z position of each node manually and problem solved.